# Are there multiple strongholds with end portals or just one?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Are there more stronghold with end portals or just one? If there are more than one, does that mean that using an eye of ender points the closest stronghold?

Comment: Please note that dungeons contain chests, mossy cobble and spawners, while strongholds contain end portals. Which are you talking about?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the 1.9 version on, there are no longer just 3 [strongholds](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stronghold).

They are now **128** per world, distributed in 8 rings (see the link above for how many generate per each ring). Their distribution is:

- The First (1st) ring with 3 strongholds ranging from 1408 to 2688 blocks away from origin.
- The Second (2nd) ring with 6 strongholds ranging from 4480 to 5760 blocks away from origin.
- The Third (3rd) ring with 10 strongholds ranging from 7552 to 8832 blocks away from origin.
- The Fourth (4th) ring with 15 strongholds ranging from 10624 to 11904 blocks away from origin.
- The Fifth (5th) ring with 21 strongholds ranging from 13696 to 14976 blocks away from origin.
- The Sixth (6th) ring with 28 strongholds ranging from 16768 to 18048 blocks away from origin.
- The Seventh (7th) ring with 36 strongholds ranging from 19840 to 21120 blocks away from origin.
- The Eight (8th) ring with 9 strongholds ranging from 22912 to 24192 block away from the origin.

Comment: I think it would be great if you could expand the answer a little, mostly regarding these rings.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I'll also do what you suggested. @MrLemon

Answer (score 18):

Default Minecraft world generates three "end dungeons" (strongholds), about 1000 blocks from the centre of the world, spread equally. That means that when you're standing at X/Z 0,0 coordinates and looking in the direction of one, the other two will be at 120° to the left and to the right. All of them have a portal to the End. The Eye of Ender, when thrown, points to the closest one.

Comment: Thank,but I forgot to mention that I'm playing on Large Biomes. @Martin Sojka

Comment: @John: If I remember correctly (don't have the code to check here ATM), that doesn't matter. It only scales up the biomes themselves, not - for example - where features like villages, abandoned mineshafts, temples or dungeons try to spawn.

Comment: Are these strongholds always in the same position from the center of the world or randomly generated as well? Ex: Is 1 of the stronghold always north of the center, or always east, etc?

Comment: No. You can see it this way: one stronghold is generated randomly in a random direction between about 600 and 1200 blocks from the origin, then the other two are placed at roughly 120° angles, also a random distance between those margins away.

Comment: @JohnOdom: They are in random directions. You'll still need the Eye of Ender (or a tool like AMIDST) to find them. It's just that relative to each other, they lie in predictable directions - once you know where one is, you can find the other two relatively easy.

Comment: This answer becomes outdated from 1.9 version on.